# Kafka producer is slow on first message

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a test application in .NET that creates kafka producer and sends a few messages to a topic using Confluent client library.

For some reason the acknowledgement for the first message always arrives 1 second late, acknowledgements for subsequent messages arrive almost immediately.

*Is this a normal behavior or am I missing some configuration?*

- I think I tried tuning all producer configs, nothing helps except setting EnableDeliveryReports = false.
- Topic is not partitioned and already exists at the moment of sending the first message.
- If I update the application to send messages to a few topics, then first message to each topic gets sent with 1 second delay.

  ```
  static void Main()
  {
      var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(new ProducerConfig
      {
          BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
          LingerMs = 100,
          BatchNumMessages = 1,
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          var start = DateTime.Now;
          producer.ProduceAsync(
              new TopicPartition("test-topic", Partition.Any), new Message<Null, string>
              {
                  Value = $"hello kafka! #{i}"
              }).Wait(2000);

          var now = DateTime.Now;
          Console.WriteLine($"{now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Message sent in {(now - start).TotalMilliseconds:N1}.");
      }

      producer.Dispose();
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
  ```

---

Sample output:

```
18:06:13.605 Message sent in 1,007.0.
18:06:13.607 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.608 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.609 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.610 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.611 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.612 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.613 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.614 Message sent in 1.0.
18:06:13.615 Message sent in 1.0.
```

Comment: I would guess it's just a cold start problem... librdkafka needs to create a batch queue in the background. If you send more than the batch size, and keep looping, you'll see periodic time delays when the batches are flushing and sent to the broker

Comment: Tried to run same example through more iterations, but only the first message has such a long delay, all the rest get acknowledged in a matter of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging in kafka request logs I found that before sending the first message producer sends API_VERSIONS and METADATA requests for all topics. After 1 second it sends again METADATA request, this time for the specific topic that producer is trying to push message to.

Setting TopicMetadataRefreshIntervalMs to something less than 1 second reduces the first message delay. As a downside producer starts sending metadata requests more often.
Surprisingly setting TopicMetadataRefreshIntervalMs to something more than a second does not extend the delay.

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: Feel free to post an issue in the Confluent dotnet Github if you think it could be a bug

Comment: Posted: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/701