# Spring Kafka Producer blocking http thread till Kafka thread complete

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have built an application using spring boot for enterprise reasons and using the spring Kafka project to publish Kafka messages.

I have been testing producing Kafka events and noticed that spring is blocking the HTTP thread till the Kafka thread is complete.

```
try {
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, OnboardingSigningNotificationEvent>> send = this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, notificationEvent);

  send.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, OnboardingSigningNotificationEvent>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, OnboardingSigningNotificationEvent> sendResult) {
      log.info("Successfully published onboarding signing notification event with record metadata timestamp: {}", sendResult.getRecordMetadata().timestamp());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
      log.error("Failure while publishing kafka event : {}", throwable.getMessage());
    }
  });
} finally {
  kafkaTemplate.flush();
}
```

This contradicts what is said in this documentation.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#sending-messages

> Notice that the send methods return a ListenableFuture.
> You can register a callback with the listener to receive the result of
> the send asynchronously.

Based on the documentation I would expect the producer call to be made asynchronously and the main http thread to not block waiting for it, but that's not what I see in my tests. Even if I block the kafka thread for a few seconds the caller http thread is being blocked.

Can you please explain whether it is on purpose and are there any config to override this behavior.

Comment: Any chances to have a simple project from you to play with? It is not clear though how you block Kafka thread... And also you don't show how you call all of this stuff...

Comment: The send doesn't block. Why are you `flush()` ing? That could block. You generally don't need it, unless you have increased `linger.ms`, but flushing on every write makes `linger.ms` pointless anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why kafka producer is very slow on first message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228639/why-kafka-producer-is-very-slow-on-first-message)